# mongoDB: Find missing documents in model tree structure with parent reference

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have some documents which are organized in a model tree structure (depth is variable!). Unfortunately some documents are missing and I need to find those broken chains. As you can see the last document in that chain has always the `target` field. This is the starting point and I have to look upwards using `parent`. The last element in that chain has always the field `type`.

```
{
    "_id" : "K7NSxNEnNSr9nCszR",
    "title" : "title",
    "type" : "book",
    "ancestors" : [ ]
}

{
    "_id" : "diyvwYz66yoTCTt9L",
    "field" : "something",
    "parent" : "K7NSxNEnNSr9nCszR",
    "ancestors" : [
        "K7NSxNEnNSr9nCszR"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "diyvwYz66yoTCTt9L",
    "field" : "anything",
    "target" : "D2YuXtM6Gzt4eWaW2",
    "parent" : "QWvdAyftSGANM3zy8",
    "ancestors" : [
        "K7NSxNEnNSr9nCszR",
        "QWvdAyftSGANM3zy8"
    ]
}
```

What I need to know is if any parent is missing or if the last element (=type existing) is missing.

```
var broken = [];
Collection.find({ target: { $exists: true }}).forEach(function(element) {
    var startDocID = element._id;
    if (Collection.find({ _id: element.parent }).count() === 0)
        broken.push(startDocID);
});

console.log(broken);
```

But this isn't working well as I need to use a loop to get upwards until the top document (= type existing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about recursion here if you need to go down the tree, so you probably need to write a recursive search function

```
var broken = [];
Collection.find({ target: { $exists: true }}).forEach(function(element) {

    function recurse(e) {
        var startDocID = e._id;
        var nodes = Collection.find({ _id: e.parent });
        if (node.count() === 0)
           {broken.push(startDocID);}
        else {
           nodes.fetch().forEach(node) {
               recurse(node)
        }
    }
    recurse(element);
}
});
```

or something of that sort... (hard to debug without the data)